# Accessing this JSON returned object

Tags: json, node.js, xml-parsing

I am doing a http call to a site that produces XML response data.

I am taking this data and parsing the content of the returned http get request call using xml2js.parseString.

The resulting data produces the following:

```
{'SearchResults:searchresults':{'$':{'xsi:schemaLocation':'http://www.zillow.com/static/xsd/SearchResults.xsd http://www.zillowstatic.com/vstatic/9520695/static/xsd/ SearchResults.xsd','xmlns:xsi':'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance','xmlns:     SearchResults':'http://www.zillow.com/static/xsd/SearchResults.xsd'},request:[[Object]],message:[[Object]],response:[[Object]]}}
```

How do I access the returned response?

FYI: When I use JSON.stringify() I can see all of the data that I need but it the JSON format is not valid and I cant access the data. I should not need to stringify the data since the data was already parsed using the xml2js and in js format, correct?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: JSON.stringify(propertyInfo, null, 2);

Comment: You indeed should not use stringify, because then the JSON object is no JSON object anymore, but a string. Where do you have troubles accessing the object? Did you put it in a variable?

Comment: Thanks for writing back , after playing around, I finally was able to drill down into this "cluster f*ck" :) Objects wrapped with arrays wrapped within more arrays... fun . Now im able to drill into the actual final json datas that I need to store into my variables! Thanks brotha

Answer (score 0):

I was not drilling down correctly into the JSON structure. Once I drilled down correctly and stored the data to variables, everything was OK!

To further expand on this answer. I want to provide the variable structure that was necessary to access the data.

For example:

```
propertyInfoJSONPath = 
propertyInfo['SearchResults:searchresults'].response[0].results[0].result[0];
```

Nothing about this was terribly complex, however, it is necessary when you are accessing JSON data that contains objects that have within them arrays to make sure to remember to always drill down and specify the initial index of 0.

Comment: "Drilling down correctly" isn't an answer. Show how you solved the problem you were having.

Comment: Just updated it with some additional details. Thanks